# How to delete the following row if duplicated data found in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, duplicates

does anyone know how to delete the following row if duplicated data found in excel using python?

Here is my input data (there are only 2 columns for input data):

```
col_1   col_2
1       number 2.37
2       number 2.8
3       number 3.4
4       number 
5       number 
6       number 
7       number 2.62
8       number 3.1
9       number 2.6
```

If duplicated data is found, the rest of the row should be deleted starting from the duplicated data. In this case, the above input data shows line 4 to line 6 is duplicated data, this means duplicated data detected, the line 4 until the end of the column which is line 9 should be deleted.

Therefore, the output should be like this (there are only 2 columns for output data):

```
col_1   col_2
1       number 2.37
2       number 2.8
3       number 3.4
```

here is my code: (but my code seems like not achieve my objective)

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_the_file)
df = df[~df.col_1.str.match('number')]
df.to_excel(path_to_the_file)
```

Any helps will be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Your dataframe is unclear as you present it. are the numbers in col_1 indexes? Or the column, as it seems. Does col_2 contain `'number 2.37'` or is number outside col_2? What does duplicated data mean, data in the row? in the same column? From your explanation, technically row 5 is the first duplicate, 4 is still unique. Together with the number. Be a bit more verbose, there are different ways of interpreting your explanation.

Comment: @MikeMajara, sorry for my poor explanation, number in col_1 just shows how many lines are there for col_2, the col_2 contain ```'number 2.37'```, the duplicated data means data in the row which is in the same column. Yes, you are correct, row 5 is the first duplicate, row 4 is still unique. However, I wish to delete row 4, row 5, row 6, row 7, row 8 and row 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_the_file)
index=df[df.duplicated(['col_2']) == True].values[0][0]
df2 = df.iloc[:index-2]
print(df2)

output:
   col_1       col_2
0      1  number2.37
1      2   number2.8
2      3   number3.4
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: @misha, thanks for your answer, I will try it later, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The case you are asking for (independent of which column is which or what 'duplicated data' means) needs a loop because slicing has its own way, it is not meant to be an iterative function. What you are stating though in your question **does depend on data found at some point** *("following row")*. So the slicing should be used once you find where that data is duplicated (if it is indeed).

[`dataframe.str.match()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) function returns a complete series that tells you if the match happens for each and every row in the dataframe. `sum` function gets you the total matches by adding the coerced boolean values to int in the series. If there is more than one match (current line + one), and only then, you can slice the df from then onwards. First row cannot be duplicate (its the first and needs no check).

The specific whereabouts of what you are trying to achieve you can work out from this example.

```
import pandas as pd

for idx,row in df[1:].iterrows(): 
    if df.col_2.str.match(df.loc[idx].col_2).sum() > 1: 
        print("found at", idx) 
        df = df[:idx] 
        break
```

*Bare in mind that this is just an example out of the box, `break` should never be used, you should use elif and explicitly define the behaviour of your code.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try it later. By the way, did you mean to replace ```elif``` or ```explicitly``` into ```break``` ?